# What to use to automatically install gulp and it's dependencies

Tags: node.js, gulp, dependencies

I have a project in which I am creating a web application by automating it using Gulp. I used **npm** to install gulp. What I want to know now is that Gulp by itself has dependencies, How can I install Gulp and it's dependencies (gulp-nodemon,gulp-run,etc) automatically just like gulp does tasks?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add those dependencies to your package.json in your project folder. If you don't have one, run `npm init` to create one. Then when you install your dependencies use the `--save` flag like so `npm install --save gulp-nodemon`